# django-treebeard Materialized Path tree depth ended up being zero

Tags: python, django, django-treebeard

I found a problematic node with id 633.

```
tree.find_problems()
([], [], [], [633], [35, 9, 50, 291, 464])
```

After running
tree.fix_tree()
It does not find any problems.

```
tree.find_problems()
([], [], [], [], [])
```

But actually 633 is still in some wierd state.

```
>>> node633.depth
0
>>> node633.path
''
```

**Problem:** node633.depth is 0 which means its not root but it does not have parent as well. Path is empty too.

This means my code will try to find parent from a node that does not have a parent.

Running fix_tree again does not fix it.
Moving node633 is not an option too because:

```
treebeard.exceptions.InvalidMoveToDescendant: Can't move node to a descendant.
```

**Some more info:**

```
django-treebeard==4.3
Django==2.2.1
```

I haven't edited paths and depths manually.

**Question:** How can i fix this broken node633?

Answer (score 0):

I think i had nothing else to do to just delete it.
I ran:

```
node633.delete()
tree.find_problems()
([], [], [], [], [])
```

Find problems is still happy.

Its **not the ideal** solution but any better solutions are welcome.